# pyvmomi perfManager - Get all stats

Tags: pyvmomi

While a am a noob in python and pyvmomi, thru the help of stackoverflow and the pyvmomi sample I have been able to get most of the information I need from ESXi servers. I want to get all the stats at the lowest level they are keeped from perfManager.  All the examples I seen deal with aggregating them over a time frame.

What I think I want to do is call query = vim.PerformanceManager.QuerySpec(maxSample=1,entity=host,metricId=[metricId],startTime=startTime,endTime=endTime)

with startTime and endTime as NULL or is python None?
and then iterate thru what comes back
I want to save the vm, datetime of the stat, the metricId and the value.
Also is there a wild card for metricId that would give me all the meticId's or do I need to call once for each metric?

I also beleve if I was to call it again later with the last datetime as the startTime and endTime as null I should get all the new stats since the last set I save? Is this correct?

Comment: This is how far I got

Comment: for vm in retProps:
  if (vm['runtime.powerState'] == "poweredOn"):
   #dump(perf_dict)
   #PrintVmInfo(vm['moref'], content, vchtime, 15, perf_dict)
   perfManager = content.perfManager
   for counter in perfList:
    counter_full = "{}.{}.{}".format(counter.groupInfo.key, counter.nameInfo.key, counter.rollupType)
    print(counter_full)
    print(counter.key)
    metricId = vim.PerformanceManager.MetricId(counterId=counter.key, instance="")

Comment: query = vim.PerformanceManager.QuerySpec(intervalId=20, entity=vm['moref'], metricId=[metricId])
    perfResults = perfManager.QueryPerf(querySpec=[query])
    for i in perfResults:
     dump(i.timestamp)

Comment: but at this point i doesn't have a attribute of timestamp. How do I access timestamp and value

Answer (score 0):

After much much searching I found this which had the few missing details.

https://github.com/dograga/ESXPerfData/blob/master/vmperfcollection_threaded.py

Comment: Link is no longer active. This answer should probably be deleted.